# margin issue. can not make a margin between two elements. misunderstanding with absolute/relative positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have problems with relative and absolute positioning. Below I have code with an example of css hover effects. There are two pics (in one div). Next I want to add another div with text. When I was trying to write smth like ".wtf {margin:300px}", the whole thing broke ))) I can't understand how to fix it. when I add for example margin for a second section: .wtf {margin-top: 100px;}, I want to get 100px space between a second section ".wtf" and a first section ".photo-line". instead of this I get 100px margin from the very up of the page, and not between sections

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<style>

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1440px;
}
.t2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 80px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    z-index: 1;
}

.img-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #6fc3df;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.pic-one {
    background-size: cover;
    background: blue;
    height: 409px;
    position: relative;
    width: 576px;
}
.pic-one:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:blue
}
.pic-two {
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: red;
    height: 409px;
    width: 864px;
    position: relative;
}
.pic-two:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
.img-overlay-two {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #8d82c4;;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.some {
    width: 1440px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2e3450;
}
.some h3, .some p {
    margin: 0;
}
.wtf {

}
</style>
<body>
<section class="photo-line">
<div class="first-part" style="width:1440px">
    <div style="float: left" class="pic-one">
        <div class="img-overlay">
        </div>
        <div class="t2">
            <h3 style="width: 240px">Aliquam</h3>
            <p>ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-part">
        <div style="float: right" class="pic-two">
            <div class="img-overlay-two"></div>
            <div class="t2">
                <h3 style="width: 240px">Tempus</h3>
                <p>feugiat amet tempus</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="wtf">
<div class="some">
    <h3>Massa libero</h3>
    <p>Nullam et orci eu l</p>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: when I add for example margin for a second section: .wtf {margin-top: 100px;}, I want to get 100px space between a second section ".wtf" and a first section ".photo-line". instead of this I get 100px margin from the very up of the page, and not between sections

Answer (score 0):

Changed answer after comment:

You `first-pic` and `second-pic` elements are floated, so their container `.first-part` will not cover them unless you add this rule:

.first-part {
  overflow: auto;
}

After that, if you add for example "margin-top: 100px`to`.wtf`, you'll get the desired vertical distance as in the snippet below.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 1440px;
}
.first-part {
  overflow: auto;
}
.t2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 80px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    z-index: 1;
}

.img-overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #6fc3df;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.pic-one {
    background-size: cover;
    background: blue;
    height: 409px;
    position: relative;
    width: 576px;
}
.pic-one:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:blue
}
.pic-two {
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: red;
    height: 409px;
    width: 864px;
    position: relative;
}
.pic-two:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
.img-overlay-two {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #8d82c4;;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
.some {
    width: 1440px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2e3450;
}
.some h3, .some p {
    margin: 0;
}
.wtf {
padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="photo-line">
<div class="first-part" style="width:1440px">
    <div style="float: left" class="pic-one">
        <div class="img-overlay">
        </div>
        <div class="t2">
            <h3 style="width: 240px">Aliquam</h3>
            <p>ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-part">
        <div style="float: right" class="pic-two">
            <div class="img-overlay-two"></div>
            <div class="t2">
                <h3 style="width: 240px">Tempus</h3>
                <p>feugiat amet tempus</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="wtf">
<div class="some">
    <h3>Massa libero</h3>
    <p>Nullam et orci eu l</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your first section doesn't have any height, while the second takes the whole page. Try adding the following style to your code:

```
.photo-line {
    overflow: auto;
}
.wtf {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```